# Refresh data in specific cell in a Div using php mysql and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am developing one application using php MySQL and AJAX.

I have one HTML Division with the table rows and columns. The example picture has been attached here.

http://niftyexpert.in/screen1.jpg

This screen is only a part in the Webpage. Now whenever I do modification I want to refresh only this cells ( Blue and Rose ).

I don't want refresh entire Timetable Division.

Real Time example we can take Gmail. First time it 3 to 5 seconds taking to load entire module.

After loaded Whenever you read mail or delete mail from inbox you can notify actions will take place specific rows not entire Division.

I need solution like that. For that What are the technologies i need to use additionally with php,mysql and ajax..

Comment: Try looking at MVVM approach. Knockout js or angular maybe.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I am using jquery ajax both.

Answer (score 0):

You load everything normally at the page request. So JS and HTML and behind it PHP and MySQL.

Then you create a function in JS, `setInterval()` that polls every few second for updates. Mostly this is the easiest having PHP output JSON data, and access that with JS to modify your HTML.

*script.js*

```
var polling = setInterval(function(){
    //AJAX GET request to web server  
    $.get("server.php", function(data){
        //on success, analyse JSON data and modify your HTML

        //for example
        if (data.cell5=='blue') 
            $('#cell5').addClass('blue');
    });

}, 5000);
```

*server.php*

```
<?
//Get MySQL info and your code on what you exactly want put it in an array

//for example
$arr['cell5'] = 'blue';

//output
echo(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

I don't know your data structure and HTML so I can't give you a better example. But you have to design some way you can easily read in JS what needs to be changed in HTML. Keep the data small so the app and data traffic is tiny. So preferable only the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this can be done using Xajax. In the below example if you type some value in Input text field and click "Cick me" button the value will be displayed inside a table row(displayOutput) without reloading the entire page.
Hope this might be useful, Look into http://www.xajax-project.org/en/home/ for more..

Download the xajax folder and place it same directory of this code and run it

```
<?php
    #this is an  userdefined xajax function, you get values from DB in it and innerHTML in HTML
    function testXajaxExample($input)
    {
        $objectResponse=new xajaxResponse();
        $output = '<td>'.$input.'</td>';
        $objectResponse->script('document.getElementById("displayOutput").innerHTML="'.$output.'"');
        return $objectResponse;
    }

    require_once('xajax/xajax_core/xajax.inc.php');
    $xajax=new xajax();
    $xajax->registerFunction('testXajaxExample');
    $xajax->processRequest();
    $xajax->printJavascript('xajax/');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Xajax Example</title>
        <script>
            function hello()
            {
                var input = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
                xajax_testXajaxExample(input);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id="exampleForm" name="exampleForm">
                <table>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>Input text</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="inputBox" name="outputBox">                          
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="clickMe" name="clickMe" value="Click Me" onclick="hello()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="displayOutput"></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```